# Use image in a SAS Stored Process's HTML Stream

Tags: image, sas, sas-stored-process

I am creating a report with SAS STP and I want to display a image(a logo) on the report. Okay here is what is happening:

```
data _null_;
    file _webout;
    put '<html>';
    put '</html>';
run;
```

I am PUTing HTML because I have complex table formats which I need to display and I am not using `%STPBEGIN` & `%STPEND` because that opens up an ODS Stream which frankly I do not know how to handle and I am having problems. Not using `%STPBEGIN` means the above code. This has been a very successful mechanism for me. I can show beautiful reports with CSS and everything. The only problem is images. A client has recently requested to put logo on every report. i though this was going to be easy but it has not been. Ok here is the deal, I tried to use `<img src=" "/ >` tag and I thought I would use some relative path and my image will show. This technique succeeded and failed.

- I added an image to a folder location using SAS Management Console
  and use its relative path '/Products/SAS Enterprise GRC/****'  (didn't work)
- I copied an image to default theme's images folder under Web/Staging/*** and tried to used the relative path (didn't work). So i tried to use other images from the the default theme. It worked.

I am stuck, how can I use a custom images here?

Comment: With second bullet point, are you saying with two different image files in Web/staging/*** one will work but not another?  If so, I would check permissions on the files to make your your file is readable.

Comment: unblocked the second image... all users have read permission.. no affect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your image is static, you can embed it into your results using a datastep without having to copy files to the server.

The trick to doing this is to encode the image into Base64 encoding, then you can embed the image into an `<img src="" />` statement by using this magical notation:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,...." />
```

You can see that the `src=` attribute contains metadata to tell the browser that the value contains image data, that represents a png file (I used a png file when testing this post, you may have a JPG/BMP etc...) and that the value is encoded using base64.  The 4 periods at the end would be replaced by your image data represented in base64 notation.  This would look something like this:

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN
... much much more base64 content here ...
HSLyz+h9xy+7HbHRL83L1tv9h8+4d/+Ic/Gf8DiYav3mpqHAMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" />`

Converting your image to base64 is simple.  You can simply google for an "online base64 image converter" such as [this one](https://www.base64-image.de/).  Drag and drop your image and it will produce your base64 code for you.

To get this into a datastep in sas, it's simply a case of:

```
data _null_;
    file _webout;
    put '<html>';
    put '<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN......etc..." />';
    put '</html>';
run;
```

If you image is particularly big (say greater than ~32k) you may run into issues trying to output it from a datastep. I probably need to test this to clarify. You can work around this by reading the base64 image from a file in SAS and streaming it directly to `_webout`, using code similar to below:

```
data _null_;
  file _webout;
  infile '\path\to\base64\file.ext';
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

---

If you want to get really tricky, you can take any image you like (such as a chart generated in SAS) and convert it to base64 on the fly, then stream it out.  Here is some SAS code that will take an image file and convert it to Base64:

```
data _null_;
  length base64_format $20 base64_string $32767;

  infile "\your_sasdir\hi.png" recfm=n;
  file "\your_sasdir\hi.base64";
  input byte $16000. ;

  * FORMAT LENGTH NEEDS TO BE 4n/3 ROUNDED UP TO NEAREST MULTIPLE OF 4;
  format_length = 4*(lengthn(byte)/3);
  mod = mod(format_length,4);
  if mod ne 0 then do;
    format_length = format_length - mod + 4;
  end;
  base64_format = cats("$base64x",format_length,".");

  base64_string = putc(cats(byte), base64_format);
  put base64_string;
run;
```

Here is the image I used to test this with:

[image]

Once converted, the Base64 representation should look like:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAIAAAAC64paAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABaSURBVDhP5YxbCsAgDAS9/6XTvJTWNUSIX3ZAYXcdGxW4QW6Khw42Axne81LG0shlRvVVLyeTI2aZ2fcPyXwPdBI8B999NK/gKTaGyxaMX8gTJRkpyREFmegBTt8lFJjOey0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

I'm going to see if I can find a way to streamline this as this is something we do frequently at work.

---

**EDIT :**  Interestingly, SAS9.4 seems to support doing this directly using `ODS HTML5` in conjunction with the `inline` option.  See the doc [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/67921/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0hcv8gpxqebnpn1is52we2enltx.htm).

See also [this post](http://hcsbi.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/the-getimage-macro-embedded-images.html), by Don Henderson, that provides a similar way to approach this problem.  Thanks to Vasilij for the link.

Comment: probably because of the IE version, it is working fine on my local browsers

Comment: Good point.  Here's a list of browsers that support it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images

Comment: guess what... This worked... turns out put statements can only hold x bytes else they mess it up... just one more thing the quality is not 100%. What's with that..

Comment: If you want to conver the file into Base64 in SAS, see this blog post: http://hcsbi.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/the-getimage-macro-embedded-images.html also the macro can be dowloaded here http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/File:Base64_getImage_Tool.zip

Comment: @Moon Using the `put _infile_` approach should circumvent the trucation issues you were having with the put statement.  Also, the image quality should not be affected in any way, I'm not sure why you are seeing that.

Answer (score 0):

When you define pictures in SAS metadata, it can be accessed via SAS Content server.
To get picture URL log into: 'https://severhost/SASContentServer/repository/default/sasfolders' and search for your picture.

If you defined your picture in catalog /Products/SAS Enterprise GRC/PictureName.gif, it should be accessible from adres 'https://severhost/SASContentServer/repository/default/sasfolders/Products/SAS Enterprise GRC/PictureName.gif(Report)'

Of course you have to remember, that customer user need to have access permission in SAS Metadata to read picture object.

If this won't solve your problem, please type which version of SAS software you are using.

Comment: I can't access sasfolders from the URI, also sasfolders is not listed when I access content server via DAVTree

Comment: also that when I access http://server-name:port/SASContentServer/dircontents.jsp. I only see `sasdav` no `sasfolders` or `sascontent`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to you once. I have added the image to our intranet which happens to be SharePoint at the time. I defined that image to have public access level and then references in all my reports.

The idea that since the report is only for internal audience, they all will have access to intranet, but not necessarily to the Content Server so it circumvents  the problem that Bagin mentioned.

If you don't have a suitable intranet, you could always reference a logo from your public website which is probably available to all of your audience even if they are external, but then you don't have control over that logo file and one day it might change in some undesirable way.

Regards,
Vasilij

Comment: yes, that could work but that's not the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [SASjs](https://sasjs.io) you can compile ANY binary content into a SAS web service (Stored Process or Viya Job).

Here's an example using an MP3 file:  https://github.com/allanbowe/sasrap