# How to embed image into SAS tagset via Base64

Tags: html, sas, base64

I'm trying to work out how to use SAS `ods tagsets` to create a single HTML output file which includes images encoded in Base64.

For automation purposes, I need to be able to take an arbitrary SAS report and create a tagset which will support images via a Base64-encoded data URI.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to do this?

Thanks,
Ricky

Comment: The image exists already on your filesystem, and you want to be able to incorporate it in your report via reference?

Comment: Are you creating your own tagset or working off a current tagset?

Comment: You can add custom HTML via ODS TEXT, if you can pass the URI through there that might work.

Comment: Re Joe: yes, the image does exist when generating the report, but the automation will put it in a location where the image does not exist. Thus, I'm trying to encode the image in Base64 and then incorporate it as a data URI directly, instead of having the image be a separate file.

Comment: Re Reeza: I'm defining my own tagset from scratch. The problem is that I don't have the Base64-encoded data URI, I have an actual image file. Also, I can't modify any of the report code, only the definition of the tagset, so I have to work within the `define event img` step.

Comment: This post might could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34732757/3412737